# using form input value in form action, Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5, frameworks

I've written some code to retrieve some data from database when a user visits a url. 
For example, When someone visits this :

```
http://localhost:8000/home/foo
```

He will see something like :

```
foome
fooyou
foohim
fooher
```

Now, I want to configure it and make an html form in my home.blade.php page.
When someone enters a query in this simple form, He should be redirected to a url just like above.
For example, Let's say that he enters "foo1" into this form. He should goes to :

```
http://localhost:8000/home/foo1
```

and see the same values as above :

```
foo1me
foo1you
foo1him
foo1her
```

So, I've used this in my controller :

```
    class DomainGeneratorController extends Controller
{
    public function keywordreturn()
    {
        return  view('home');
    }
    public function userkeyword(Request $inputtedkeyword, $id)
    {
        $blog = DB::table('keywords')->pluck('blog');
        $hosting = DB::table('keywords')->pluck('hosting');
        return view('home', ['inputtedkeyword' => $id, 'category' => $blog]);
    }
}
```

and here is my routes :

```
Route::get('/', 'DomainGeneratorController@keywordreturn');

Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'DomainGeneratorController@keywordreturn');
Route::resource('home/{id}', 'DomainGeneratorController@userkeyword');
```

Finally, Here is home.blade.php :

```
<div class="panel-body">
    @if(isset($category))
        <table>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Keyword</td>
                <td>.COM</td>
                <td>.NET</td>
                <td>.ORG</td>
            </tr>
            @foreach( $category as $item )
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $inputtedkeyword }}{{ $item }}</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $item }}{{ $inputtedkeyword }}</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    @else
        <p>Enter your own keyword</p>

        <form method="POST" id="domaininput"
              action="{{ action('DomainGeneratorController@userkeyword', $id = Request::get("find")) }}">
            <div id="check" class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="find" placeholder="Search">
                <button type="submit">
                    <div id="search" class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </div>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    @endif
</div>
```

Where am I doing wrong? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Some changes need to make

1. Use routing

   ```
    Route::post('home', 'DomainGeneratorController@userkeyword');
   ```
2. It's totally opposite , also change here

   ```
    <form method="POST" id="domaininput"
         action="/home">
   ```
3. Get post value

   ```
    return view('home', ['inputtedkeyword' => $inputtedkeyword->find, 'category' => $blog]);
   ```

Comment: What error are you getting? What's not working as intended?